# URL Hack Lightning with % in URL Encode

Tags: lightning, url, urlhacking, url-encode

I am attempting to utilize URL Hacking in lightning it has worked great until I faced having to pass a % in a stage name to the new record. It seems to be encoding properly but it still just renders a blank aura screen.

Here is the URL before encoding:

```
/lightning/o/Event/new?recordTypeId=0120c000001hiFPAAY&defaultFieldValues=WhatId=001j000000Wn6EtAAJ,field1__c=Qualify 25%,field2__c=Specialty,field3__c=SubSpecialty&count=1&backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Opportunity/0065C000005x8PqQAI/view
```

Then with encoding:

```
/lightning/o/Event/new?recordTypeId=0120c000001hiFPAAY&defaultFieldValues=WhatId%3D001j000000Wn6EtAAJ%2Cfield1__c%3DQualify%2025%25%2Cfield2__c%3DSpecialty%2Cfield3__c%3DSubSpecialty&count=1&backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Opportunity/0065C000005x8PqQAI/view
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't pass correctly? If I removed the %25 representing the % symbol it works.